# ArrayList not removing item

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Hi for some strange reason i cant remove an item from the **ArrayList**, it removes the first 4 items but it will not remove **City** from the list any suggestions would be great. Thanks

```
    String str = getset.getFILEMESSAGE();
    ArrayList aList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
    for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(aList.get(i));
    System.out.println(aList.size());
    }
     aList.remove("Person ID");
        aList.remove("First Name");
        aList.remove("Last Name");
        aList.remove("Street");
        aList.remove("City");


      System.out.println(aList);
      System.out.println(aList.size());
      String convertedmessage = aList.toString();

      System.out.println("converted message = " + convertedmessage);
```

Comment: What's the output look like?

Comment: Is `"City"` in the list ?

Comment: Check if there is a hidden character such as '\n'

Comment: What's the value of `str` after the first line? It's kind of important to the question!

Comment: Replace `getset.getFILEMESSAGE()` in your sample code with the String you are about to split. Then we may help.

Comment: Try trimming the strings before adding/removing to/from the list.

Comment: City is in the list .. heres the output converted message = [City
1, Ola, Hansen, Timoteivn, Sandnes

2, Tove, Svendson, Borgvn, Stavanger
3, Kari, Pettersen, Storgt, Stavanger
]

Comment: You need to remove `City 1` instead of `City`.

Comment: @NasirShiraz in list which you displayed `City` is not in the list, `City 1` is, and they are two different objects

Comment: Please print the str so we can understand whats the input

Comment: Please show the content of the for loop at the time of execution.That is the datas inside the **ArrayList**

Comment: i tried changing City 1 that didnt work i need the 1 in my list for the person id  heres the string Person ID,First Name,Last Name,Street,City
1,Ola,Hansen,Timoteivn,Sandnes

2,Tove,Svendson,Borgvn,Stavanger
3,Kari,Pettersen,Storgt,Stavanger

Comment: Post the input data. We need to see what is in `getset.getFILEMESSAGE()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems to be correct if all entries contain the same content/value. However your comment

> i tried changing City 1 that didnt work i need the 1 in my list for the person id heres the string Person ID,First Name,Last Name,Street,City 1,Ola,Hansen,Timoteivn,Sandnes 2,Tove,Svendson,Borgvn,Stavanger 3,Kari,Pettersen,Storgt,Stavanger

implies, that the values are changing. The anwser of JajaDrinker looks correct but if you want to keep it really simple I would just remove the entries by their index. Since they are all at the beginnig, the following code will delete the first five entries of your list and should always do the job.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    aList.remove(0);
```

Comment: thanks that worked, it removed the city.. Thank you everyone for all the help .. gratefully appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you say in your comments the string is:
"Person ID,First Name,Last Name,Street,City,Ola,Hansen,Timoteivn,Sandnes 2,Tove,Svendson,Borgvn,Stavanger 3,Kari,Pettersen,Storgt,Stavanger"

If that is true then your code is working.
The final output with that String would be:
converted message = [Ola, Hansen, Timoteivn, Sandnes 2, Tove, Svendson, Borgvn, Stavanger 3, Kari, Pettersen, Storgt, Stavanger]

So I am pretty sure that there is a problem with the String.
Try using debugger and show us the actual contents of the String during the execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = getset.getFILEMESSAGE();
ArrayList aList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
for (int i = 0; i < aList.size(); i++) {

    if(aList.get(i).startsWith("City")){

         String tmpString = aList.get(i);
         String[] stringTab= new String[2];
          stringTab=  tmpString.split(" "); 
         aList.get(i) = stringTab[1];

    }else if(....){ //Do the same for the others

      aList.remove(i);
      i--;

    }

    System.out.println(aList.get(i));
    System.out.println(aList.size());
}
      System.out.println(aList);
  System.out.println(aList.size());
  String convertedmessage = aList.toString();

   System.out.println("converted message = " + convertedmessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably remove the strings you don't need before splitting the array... like this ...

```
String str = getset.getFILEMESSAGE();
String strWithOutIDNameStreetCity = str.substring(str.indexOf("City")+"City".length());
```

Then split it and it contains only the stuff you need.

Comment: hi that code removes the City but it also removes the 1st line heres the output converted message3 = 2, Tove, Svendson, Borgvn, Stavanger
3, Kari, Pettersen, Storgt, Stavanger
]